# Can this be done with the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am thinking of starting a website that allows users to download files in exchange for them sharing the download page on Facebook.

So the general idea is the user logs into the website with their Facebook account and grants the App permissions to post for them. Whenever they download a file, it is posted to their wall.

I know forcing a user to share is against Facebook TOS but forcing a user to like isn't. I don't know the rules when it comes to Facebook Apps.

Any advice or information on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why did you tag this with java, javascript and php? There is no programming question whatsoever. This is a legal question.

Comment: I'm also asking the best way to get the share effect. Through an App or just using the share function. I thought the tags would be relevant to that side of my question.

Comment: But that is not a java/php/javascript question either. What is your problem with java/php/javascript? Did you try to do something that did not work? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: No, I am asking for advice. I don't know if this is possible so I thought that someone who is an expert in Java would be able to tell me if it was possible.

Comment: It's possible but not sure about the ToS. Your best bet is to start building it and if you are stuck with a particular problem code related then post it here but not sure if there are many who know if this type of functionality is frowned upon by Facebook. There's a group on Facebook that you could ask on: http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/?fref=ts

Comment: IMO you should never force a user to do anything in Facebook or via Facebook as it just leads to bad user experience and looks like spam/phishing

Comment: _“I know forcing a user to share is against Facebook TOS”_ – that’s your answer right there already: It’s not allowed, period. https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration